# Warframe offline segment for customization

Tags: warframe

Why can't I customize my weaponry? It keeps saying offline segment but I haven't had this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to complete Vor's Prize in order to get the appropriate landing craft segment to place in the Arsenal.